# Canvas alt tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, alt

I am trying to create a js code to grab an image and replace it with a canvas element so I can create a clipping path that works on all browsers.  The client wants to utilize the alt tags, is there a way to use alt tags with a canvas element?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the `alt` attribute (for an `img` element) is to provide a text alternative, which can get used if the image is not available or if the image can’t be perceived.

The [`canvas` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/semantics-scripting.html#the-canvas-element) can’t have an `alt` attribute, but you have to provide content that

> […] conveys essentially the same function or purpose as the `canvas`'s bitmap".

So this serves a similar purpose.

One way of doing this is to add it as content of the `canvas` element (whereby it becomes "fallback content"):

```html
<canvas>
  <!-- fallback content here -->
</canvas>
```